# Browser-widget geoblocking and IP

Tags: livecode

When using the browser-widget of Livecode I have the following problems:
as target URL I use "www.tagesschau.de" and when I select the live stream I get the following message:

> "Running this clip needs Flash-Plug-in up from Version 10.2"

The other error mess is:

> "this video cannot be shown, due to Geoblocking it can accessed only from germany"

This means that browser shows up in the URL with a different IP than mine in the router. On my host-system everything works well. How can this happen without VPN?

Perhaps the properties of browser can be changed somewhere in the livecode-system. Where to put in the Flash-plugin and where to correct the IP?

Who can help? I need this functionality!
Thanks

Comment: You must add (part of) the script that causes the problem. Without code, it is impossible to see if you made a mistake. Could you point the browser widget to http://economy-x-talk.com/ip.php and check the IP address?